# Error after update to Xamarin.Forms 5.0 and Android 10: MAX_PATH

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

Project worked perfect until i updated from `Xamarin.Forms 4.8` to `Xamarin.Forms 5.0` and Target Framework from `Android 9.0` to `Android 10.0`.
This is the error i get:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error       Failed to generate Java type for class: Google.Android.Material.BottomNavigation.BottomNavigationView/IOnNavigationItemReselectedListenerImplementor due to MAX_PATH: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\vaskoj\Desktop\InstagramCloneInterviewApp\InstagramCloneInterviewApp\InstagramCloneInterviewApp.Android\obj\Debug\100\android\src\mono\com\google\android\material\bottomnavigation\BottomNavigationView_OnNavigationItemReselectedListenerImplementor.java'.
> at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
> at System.IO.File.InternalDelete(String path, Boolean checkHost)
> at System.IO.File.Delete(String path)
> at Xamarin.Android.Tools.Files.CopyIfStreamChanged(Stream stream, String destination)
> at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.GenerateJavaStubs.CreateJavaSources(IEnumerable`1 javaTypes, TypeDefinitionCache cache) InstagramCloneInterviewApp.Android

Someone have the same problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try moving your solution folder to a shorter path (closer to the root), for example move it to root folder "D:" or "C:".

You have reached the the maximum length for a path which is defined by `MAX_PATH` [Maximum Path Length Limitation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#maximum-path-length-limitation)

Comment: I added in C:\ProjectName  and Clear/Rebuild Project and that fixed my problem. @Cfun can u add little explanation why this is happening?

Comment: I have added the documentation link about the issue you encountered, I have encountered the same issue few months ago :)